# How to view included SSI file

Tags: html, ssi

Is there any possibility to view the virtual included SSI file, for example with eclipse?

In this example: 
http://www.ssi-developer.net/ssi/ssi_page_template.shtml
how to view `top-links.shtml` ?

Comment: It's a file … so `File > Open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect you have to have access to the directory that the file is in and open it directly.  Opening it via the web URL will likely not succeed because it's usually filtered by the web server.